# How install self signed Cert in ubuntu on localhost

Tags: ssl, localhost

I just use the paypal payment method. when entering buyer account id and password it gives the warning

`Don’t see the secure PayPal browser? We’ll help you re-launch the window to complete your purchase`

Can anyone guide how to install self-signed SSL?

I  am using `Ubuntu 18.04` and not make any **vhost**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've not said whether you are using nginx or Apache

This for nginx

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-self-signed-ssl-certificate-for-nginx-in-ubuntu-18-04

This for Apache

https://medium.com/@chiragpatel_52497/create-a-self-signed-ssl-certificate-for-apache2-http-in-ubuntu-18-04-14ce7b3f8421

The process is too lengthy for me to put into SO

That all said if you are using PayPal which comes with magento under the advanced tab set Enable SSL verification to No

https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/Resources/Images/config-sales-payment-methods-paypal-payments-advanced-advanced-settings_thumb_0_0.png